# Buy item from amazon programmatically with C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I need to buy item from Amazon.com programmatically without redirect to amazon web site for money withdraw?

Comment: I dearly hope that this is not possible.

Answer (score 7):

What I get from your question is you need Amazon as an underlying service for your applciation.

Have a look at

- [**Amazon WebServices Api**](http://aws.amazon.com/)

and particularly this

- [**Checkout by Amazon**](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business?sn=cba/o)
- [**What Your Customers See**](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business?sn=cba/what)
- [**Amazon Simple Pay**](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business?sn=paynow/o)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little bit unclear, but I take it to mean that you would like to use Amazon Flexible Payment Service to complete a payment transaction without having the person who is paying sign in to their Amazon account and approve the payment. Yes?

***You can't.***

It is an intentional security measure. It prevents you from defrauding somebody.

Comment: What if he works for a while first in Amazon Mechanical Turk?

Comment: Nope, not even The Turk can do this.

Comment: Yes, i ment that i need to process payment without the person. Thanks

Comment: You can't do it, Victor, sorry. You may be able to do this with recent updates to the PayPal API, but Amazon won't let you. It is a security/fraud risk.